# How do I get the output of a vim 8.0 job?

Tags: job-control

I wanted to try vim 8.0's new job start feature with a simple "hello world" style example. I tried:

```
:let job = job_start('ls -alh')
```

but there is no output. I tried

```
echo job_info(job)
```

and that output:

```
{'status': 'dead', 'stoponexit': 'term', 'exitval': 0, 'exit_cb': 0, 'channel': channel 2 closed, 'process': 32415}
```

not not the output of the job. how can I get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim jobs start with a channel, you can use `job-options` to redirect output to a buffer. For example:

```
:let job = job_start('ls -alh', {'out_io': 'buffer', 'out_name': 'mybuffer'})
```

then

```
:sbuf mybuffer
```

to read it.

Ref: [`:h job-start`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/channel.txt.html#job-start).

Escaping issues (dependent on the platform) can be fixed with a list ([issue 1539](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1539#issuecomment-291433247)):

```
let args = ['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd]
```